# Django Error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How To Fix This Error:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'
```

I Want to Create User Profile I'm Tired To Fix!

I Want To Create User Page When He Register But I get this error again and again

**Base.Html**

```
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <li class="nav-item">

    <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'profile' pk=user.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">

    <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'logout' %}"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>&nbsp; Logout</a>
  </li>

  {% else %}
  <li class="nav-item">

    <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'register' %}"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>&nbsp; Sign up Free</a>
  </li>    
  <li class="nav-item">

    <a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'login' %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Login</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
```

**Urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='index'),
    path('accounts/signup/', views.user_reg,name='register'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>',views.profile_detail,name='profile')

]
```

**Views.py**

```
def profile_detail(request,pk):
    pk = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    model = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    template_name = 'profile_detail_view.html'
```

Here is my **Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class user_register_model(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profile",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

**ERROR:**

[image]

Any Help Appreciated 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def profile_detail(request,pk):
    pk = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    model = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    template_name = 'profile_detail_view.html'
```

try to remove the following line:

```
pk = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Comment: Hi I Need To Create Url Profile it Work But I Want Also If Anyone Logout It Can Show Person Profile

Comment: ```@HamzaLachi``` are you asking to show a user profile to everyone?

Comment: yes You Are Right I'm Trying To Show Profile To Everyone

Comment: Anyway Thanks For My Help Up-voted and Answer Accepted and i up-vote your all question ad answer Again Thanks!

Comment: ```@HamzaLachi``` public profile and create or edit user's own profile should be different. The main differences 1) do not need the ```{% if user.is_authenticated %}``` 2)in ``` "{% url 'profile' pk=user.pk %}" ``` , pk could be ```pk=post.author.pk```, something like that. Thanks a lot for up-votes!

Comment: @haneul Can You Please Answer Me On My This Question So I Can Understand Better! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812153/how-to-show-user-profile-to-everyone-by-link-in-django

Answer (score 0):

In the profile path you want to pass user id to the url as parameter:

> path('profile/',views.profile_detail,name='profile')

But you passing the user model into it instead of the id in the template:

```
<a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'profile' pk=user.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Profile</a>
```

It should be like this:

```
<a class="nav-link navaour" href="{% url 'profile' pk=user.id %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Profile</a>
```

And you need to fix to view to convert pk string to int for query:

```
def profile_detail(request,pk):
    model = get_object_or_404(User, pk=int(pk))
    template_name = 'profile_detail_view.html'
```

Comment: Still Getting Same Error!

Comment: can you post full stacktrace of the error to your question ?

Comment: Question Updated Please Check!

Comment: There is your problem you passing string pk to the get object query that require int]

Answer (score 0):

```
class user_register_model(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profile",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Add **str** function to your models

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a problem in your `views.py` the code `User.objects.get(pk=pk)`, returns the User object. So your code must be

```
user=User.objects.get(pk=pk)

model = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user.pk)
```