# How To Show User Profile To Everyone By Link! in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-users

How To Show User Profile To Everyone By Link! in Django

I Want To Show User Profile To Everyone for-example if someone type this in browser domain.com/profile/1

Then Our First User Profile Want To Show

But it's showing blank

It's showing when user login but we need to show to everyone

Here is my **detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}

<h1 class="posttitle">{{user.username}}</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is my **Views.py**

```
def profile_detail(request,pk):
    model = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    return render(request,'profile_detail_view.html')
```

If You Need More Files Like Model,Views,Url Something Let me down in comment i will update my question

Any Help Will Be Appreciated

Thanks!!

Comment: can you show your views which renders the `detail.html`

Comment: @arjun Question updated

Comment: @HamzaLachi I see you have 'posttitle', is the user linked to another model, such as Post?

Comment: @ha-neul No it's not it's only class

Comment: @ha-neul i get my answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the user instance to the detail.html .

```
def profile_detail(request,pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    return render(request,'profile_detail_view.html',{'user':user})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is typo or intentional but in your question you have mentioned template name as `detail.html` however your view is rendering a different template `profile_detail_view.html`.

Also I see you have not passed any context data to the template, so you need to fix that and finally please ensure your `urls.py` is setup properly to serve this route.

```
def profile_detail(request,pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    return render(request,'detail.html', {'user':user})
```